# jquery animation bottom right to left top

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a responsive webpage where if you click on a circle in the middle of the screen a div will enlarge from the circle to the top left of the webpage. what you would need is a negative hight... I searched online for quite some time but couldn't find an answer although i think this is quite a common problem...

Although this code does not work, this is roughly what it should do:

```
$(".corner").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({width: '-400px', height: '-400px'}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: can you post your html markup as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what exactly isn't working with your solution, but I've come up with a bit of an alternative. It involves resizing the div to +400px/+400px and repositioning, instead of resizing to a negative width/height.

Here is the relevant JS, slightly modified from your own:

```
$(".corner").click(function(){
    $(this).css({position: 'relative'});
    $(this).animate({right: '400px', bottom: '400px', width: '400px', height: '400px'}, 1000);
});
```

And [a supplementary JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFrye333/aTepf) as well. I'm using a square div instead of a circle and I've given it a margin to give it room to grow upward and leftward, but I hope that you get the idea.

Let me know what you think of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
$(".corner").click(function(e){
    $new_width = $(e.target).width() + e.clientX;
    $new_height =  $(e.target).height() + e.clientY;
    $(e.target).animate(
        { top:0, left:0, width: $new_width, height: $new_height }, 1000
    );
});
```

Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ese4C/3/)